# Theory behind scipy.cKDTree.query_ball_point()?

Tags: python, scipy, computer-vision, computer-science

Where can I find the theory behind the scipy.cKDTree.query_ball_point() method?

I am using pykdtree library (https://github.com/storpipfugl/pykdtree) which while closely adopting methods from scipy.cKDTree module, does not have an implementation for the .query_ball_point() method.

The dataset I am using, it seems to favor pykdtree's built-in parallelization than scipy.cKDTree. scipy.cKDTree works but it has a large time impact (~avg 90ms) which for the SLAM application that I am working on is quite significant.

Comment: If you want to know what exactly it is doing, it is finding the points from an another point within a given range

Comment: @McLovin Thanks for the heads up. Is it possible to replicate the .query_ball_point() with the .query() method and for-loops? How to ascertain that out of the indices of keypoints returned only a select few within the radius is present?

Comment: Should be possible. The `.query` is returning the indices of nearest neighbors and their corresponding distances. You can this information in a loop to get what you need. See the documentation: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.query.html#scipy.spatial.KDTree.query

Comment: @McLovin Thanks for the heads up regarding the returned distances. I had forgotten `.query` method provides that information too. I think two for-loop should do it but I will try to vectorize the second loop if possible. Will get back to you soon